# How do I open a URL in my app instead of the web browser?

Tags: java, android, onesignal

I have an app made web in app and at the moment of sending a notification with onesignal I would like it to open directly from the app and not from a modal or internal browser of the same

Comment: By "open" do you mean you want the response in your app, so you can process it in your code? Or do you mean that you want a pane in your app UI to show the page, as if the pane was a mini-browser?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy. Follow the steps:

1. Create New Activity
2. Fill it with [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)
3. Start that particular activity instead of throwing an intent to Android OS